# Time invariant system

Tags: lti-system

Is the system \$y(t) = x(t-2) + x(2-t)\$ time invariant?

Here is my solution:

Let \$x_1(t)\$ be an arbitrary input, then the corresponding output is:

\$y_1(t) = x_1(t-2) + x_1(2-t)\$

Let \$x_2(t) = x_1(t-t_0)\$, then the corresponding output is:

\$
\begin{align}
y_2(t) ={} & x_2(t-2) + x_2(2-t) \\
={} & x_1(t-t_0-2) + x_2(2-t+t_0) \\
={} & y_1(t-t_0)
\end{align}
\$

Since \$y_2(t) = y_1(t-t_0)\$ the system is time invariant. Is this solution correct? Because the manuel solution of my book (signals and systems by Oppenhiem) says that this system is time variant.

Comment: the solution book is correct. you've not correctly shifted the time.

Comment: Try for the simple case where y(t) = x(-t).

Comment: [Related 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/460812/238590)

Comment: [Related 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/458591/238590) [Related 2.5](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/458597/238590)

Answer (score 2):

The time inversion is what is creating the time dependence. It requires knowledge of absolute time (absolute time 1s in your case) 0s absolute time in the below example. The delayed system output y(t-1) is **not** the same as the system output y2(t) for delayed input x(t-1).

signal x(t) is assumed as x(t) = t for convenience. Nothing special.

[image: time variance picture illustrative]

Comment: So how do you show that algebraically as the OP tried to?

Comment: I couldn't spot the mistake in OP's derivation either :)  I guessed the time variance is coming from the \$-t\$ and checked it by drawing a diagram :) @DKNguyen

Comment: To do it algebraically, I remember using an additional variable like \$\tau\$ in such problems. But I can't replicate it reliably :)

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Doing something like time shifting the output, and time shifting the input, and comparing the two to see if they match or don't match doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I did a trivial mistake. Here is the correct algebraic solution :

Let x1(t) be an arbitrary input, then the corresponding output is :

y1(t) = x1(t-2) + x1(2-t)

Let x2(t) = x1(t-to), then the corresponding output is :

y2(t) = x2(t-2) + x2(2-t) = x1(t-to-2) + x1(2-t-to)

And  y1(t-to)=x1(t-to-2) + x1(2-t+to)

Since y2(t) does not equal y1(t-to) the system is time-variant.

Comment: x2(2-\$\tau\$)  -> x1(2-t-to) Is that valid? Didn't you just say \$\tau\$ = t-to when you let x2(t) = x1(t-to)?

Comment: X2(2-t) means that you go to x1(t-to) and substitute t by 2-t.

Comment: Oh, I'll have to go back and review. It's been a really long time but this morning when I was reading your post I had the feeling that if you did that it would make all systems time variant so I ruled it out. I think this is what AJN was talking about he said you add an addition variable \$\tau\$ in, because it makes it really confusing when you have different versions of t floating around.

Answer (score 1):

First comment on the other answer prompted this answer.

First thing to note is that systems described by equations like \$y_1(t) = 2x(t)\$, or \$y_2(t) = (x(t))^2\$, or \$y_3(t) = 2 + x(t)\$ etc. map the amplitude of the signal. It should also be noted that different mappings are indicated by different symbols or symbol combinations which result in unambiguous representations. While drawing the graphs for these, we use different *y-axes* for the signals and name them differently (y(t), x(t) etc.).

Systems described by equations like \$y_1(t) = x(t-2)\$, or \$y_2(t) = x(-t)\$ do a mapping between the time axes. **It would benefit to use unique symbols for the time axes of each signal.**

e.g. #1

\$y_1(\tau_1) = x(t)\$, where the mapping is \$\tau_1 \mapsto t = \tau_1-2\$ clearly indicates that \$y_1(2) = x(0)\$ and so on.

e.g. #2

\$y_2(\tau_2) = x(t)\$, where \$\tau_2 \mapsto t = -\tau_2\$ clearly indicates that \$y(5) = x(-5)\$ and so on, while reminding us that the signals exist on *different* time axes with a mapping existing between the time axes.

### Checking time invariance for a simple case

With that out of the way, lets tackle the time invariance of the simple system described by
\$y(t) = x(-t)\$.

We will re-write it as
\$y(\tau) = x(t), t = -\tau\$. To check for time invariance we need to compare the output for the time shifted input (denoted as \$y_2\$ and \$x_2\$ respectively) to the time shifted output of the original input (denoted as \$y_3\$ and \$x\$ respectively). The diagram showing the various signals and the mappings are shown below

[image: diagram showing the mappings. does it commute?]

With the diagram and the algebraic relations between the various time axes clearly marked, we can see that

\$y_3(\tau_3) = x(t),\ \ \ t = -\tau = -(\tau_3 - t_0) = -\tau_3 \color{red}{+} t_0\$

and

\$y_2(\tau_2) = x(t),\ \ \ t = \tau_1 - t_0 = -\tau_2 \color{red}{-} t_0\$

Comparison shows a sign difference (marked in red colour). The system is time variant.

### Another example

Let system be \$y(t) = x(2t)\$. Let's re write as

\$y(\tau) = x(t),\ \ \ t = 2\tau\$.

We see that \$y(4) = x(8)\$ as so on.

Following same naming convention and procedure as above,

\$y_3(\tau_3) = x(t),\ \ \ t = 2\tau = 2(\tau_3 - t_0) = 2\tau_3 - \color{red}{2}t_0\$

and

\$y_2(\tau_2) = x(t),\ \ \ t = \tau_1 - t_0 = 2\tau_2 - t_0\$

This system is also time variant.

### Notes

1. The method doesn't require the diagram; only the algebraic relations b/w the time axes. diagram is only for convenience
2. Both examples show time variant property since knowledge of the absolute zero time is required.
3. Systems can have mapping on the time and amplitude axes together. e.g. \$y(t) = 2 * x(t-3)\$. Simple examples shown above are chosen for ... well, simplicity.
4. The first example with \$y(t) = x(-t)\$ can be compared with the figure in my other answer to see if the signal relations are worked out correctly.

Comment: second example (\$x(2t)\$) is shown [here also](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digital_signal_processing/dsp_time_invariant_systems.htm)

Comment: [An SE answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/460812/238590) using re-naming of time variable.